# Is there a way to represent the changes over time in a graph of the knowledge base in grakn?

Tags: vaticle-typedb

Given a context, for example, you do have a set of facts in your graph database / knowledge base (as in the grakn), that would represent a current state of a graph (in plain text here) like :

1. version 1 (jan/2016): "Rachel is a person that is a english teacher for a class of 10 students in a University ABC" .
2. change 1 (mar/2016), that generates version 2: "Alice replaces Rachel"
3. version 2: (mar/2016): "Alice is a person that is a english teacher for a class of 10 students in a University ABC".

So given that, I know that I could represent the versions inside the graph and replicate everything (minus the change) from version 1 into a new set of the data (nodes and edges) to the version 2,

But I am wondering if there is a Best Practice (or some mechanism of the engine) in representing these changes overtime, like versioning of that data set, or something similar that would make the change to a new data set but keep a history so that you can recompose the previous state the graph.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing close to that is that Grakn can support attaching attributes to relationships. For example:

```
insert 
$x (spouse: $p1, spouse: $p2) isa marriage;
$x has date "01/10/2010"
```

You can also attach attributes to attributes. So if you defined a attribute type for example `Version` you could attach that to all your relationships.

So while it cannot represent change over time out of the box you can work around it to some degrees depending on your use case.